# Windows 7 "Upgrade was not successful"

Tags: windows-7, windows

When trying to upgrade from Vista to Windows 7, the installer gets up to the last step, and then gives me the message "The upgrade was no successful. Your previous version of Windows is being restored." What is with this? Others (Albeit few) have commented with the same issue, and report this occurring even after a clean install.

It's very annoying because it doesn't give any reason for this problem. I can't believe that some group of dedicated developers over at Microsoft thought it would be a good idea to say "well, if the upgrader doesnt work, lets just not give them any reason for the error and tell them they're gonna go back to Vista"

What kind of solution am I supposed to come up with. O.K. I bought Windows 7, it says it's unsucessful, now what? Am I supposed to put the disk into my drawer and wait for Windows 8?

Comment: although i do have the greatest sympathy for you, please refrain from using inapropriate language.

Comment: My apologies. I was so upset during the writing of this question, that I didn't actually realize I had used any inappropriate words. After thinking about it, of course there isn't any reason to use such words! This isn't an x-rated question forum after all!

Comment: Whilst this is not an answer, I would never upgrade any operating system (whether Windows, Linux or something else). It always causes weird problems sooner or later. Keep your documents on a separate partition, then a re-install or new OS version is trivially easy.

Comment: Why don't you call or email Microsoft? Ask them for asistance; they're in the best position to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest downloading and installing the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15). It will give you specifics as to what is not compatible with Windows 7 and it will tell you the problem areas you may want to upgrade. It should shed some light as to what the problem is, rather than giving you an error and no reason at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was hoping that the Upgrade Advisor would clear at least something up, but I don't think it did. It told me that I could possibly uninstall Itunes, but I can't imagine that being the cause of the problem, or else this would be a much more common problem.

Answer (score 0):

That Upgrade Advisor is usually spot on - if verbose.  Assuming you have studied it's every nuance not just the itunes.  I will move on to other ideas.

1) Check the Device Manager in Vista any ?? anything dodgy, fix before you upgrade.  In particular display drivers.

2) This is off the wall but works. Remove the network cable!!  Some say this stops the install trying to send messages to Microsoft, it can't so it sulks and aborts the install.

3) Does it stop at a precise % e.g. there's lots of forum messages about 62% hangs and also 63% errors.  As ever the more info you give the more chance someone will have seen this before.

More research on [Vista Upgrade problems](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_upgrade_how_to.htm)